# Can't Display Version of a Python Binary PEX with Click Entry Points

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-click, python-pex

### Python Click CLI Application

When you use a Click library to build a Python CLI Application you can do this:

```py
@click.version_option()
def cli():
    '''
    Main Entry Point to Click Interface
    '''
```

to be able to do this:

```sh
[user@host]$ clickapp --version
```

### Click Packaged in `pex`

But when I package it as a `pex` file, every other argument, option, commands, sub-command of my click application works, except `--version`.

When I run (clickapp is now a binary executable `pex` file):

```sh
[user@host]$ ./clickapp --version
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/~/clickapp/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 446, in execute
  File "/~/clickapp/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 378, in _wrap_coverage
  File "/~/clickapp/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 409, in _wrap_profiling
  File "/~/clickapp/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 508, in _execute
  File "/~/clickapp/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 610, in execute_entry
  File "/~/clickapp/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 626, in execute_pkg_resources
  File "/~/.pex/installed_wheels/7bcb1b5bf49ca3f89c348c338d33c04e3d59dfc1/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/~/.pex/installed_wheels/7bcb1b5bf49ca3f89c348c338d33c04e3d59dfc1/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/click/core.py", line 781, in main
    with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
  File "/~/.pex/installed_wheels/7bcb1b5bf49ca3f89c348c338d33c04e3d59dfc1/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/click/core.py", line 700, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/~/.pex/installed_wheels/7bcb1b5bf49ca3f89c348c338d33c04e3d59dfc1/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/click/core.py", line 1212, in parse_args
    rest = Command.parse_args(self, ctx, args)
  File "/~/.pex/installed_wheels/7bcb1b5bf49ca3f89c348c338d33c04e3d59dfc1/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/click/core.py", line 1048, in parse_args
    value, args = param.handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
  File "/~/.pex/installed_wheels/7bcb1b5bf49ca3f89c348c338d33c04e3d59dfc1/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/click/core.py", line 1630, in handle_parse_result
    value = invoke_param_callback(self.callback, ctx, self, value)
  File "/~/.pex/installed_wheels/7bcb1b5bf49ca3f89c348c338d33c04e3d59dfc1/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/click/core.py", line 123, in invoke_param_callback
    return callback(ctx, param, value)
  File "/~/.pex/installed_wheels/7bcb1b5bf49ca3f89c348c338d33c04e3d59dfc1/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/click/decorators.py", line 295, in callback
    raise RuntimeError("Could not determine version")
RuntimeError: Could not determine version
```

#### Details

The `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name='clickapp',
    version='0.1.3',
    author='Hamza M Zubair',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={
        '': ['*.yaml'],
    },
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'License :: Other/Proprietary License',
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=[
        'click',
        'pandas',
        'sqlalchemy',
        'jinjasql',
        'pyyaml',
        'joblib',
        'python-dateutil',
        'loguru',
        'pymysql',
        'xgboost',
        'sklearn',
        'wheel',
        'importlib-resources'
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        clickapp=clickapp.cli:cli
    ''',
)
```

The command used to create the `pex` file:

```sh
[user@host]$ python setup.py bdist_pex --bdist-all
```

#### Tool Specs

I am building and running the pex file in different systems, using the following versions of libraries/packages. The target machine only has Python and no libraries, because pex file does not require libraries/virtualenv etc.

```
Build Machine OS: CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)  
Build Machine Python: 3.6.8  
setuptools: 51.0.0  
pex: 2.1.21  
click: 7.1.2  
Target Machine OS: CentOS Linus release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Target Machine Python: 3.6.8
```

### What I tried

1. I have tested the full functionality of my `clickapp`, and every other argument and command works perfectly.

Even this displays the help of my clickapp correctly.

```
[user@host]$ ./clickapp --help
```

1. I tried re-building the package several times
2. I have only tested this in Python3.6. I haven't tried different python versions, its slightly difficult to set it up in both the source and target systems.
3. When I removed `@click.version_option()` I get the error: `--version not implemented`, which is just as expected
4. I am yet to test it on a 2nd target system, in case some idiosyncrasies of my current target server is causing the error

#### More Info

What other information should I provide, for helping SO users?

Comment: Looks like there is a bug somewhere. Or at least an incompatibility between _click_ and _pex_. Maybe the technique _click_ uses to look up the version number does not work when running from a _pex_.

Comment: Maybe show the `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml`), and show the command used to build the _pex_.

Comment: @sinoroc Good Idea, added `setup.py` and the command

Comment: I am looking at _click_'s code and something is strange to me... Could you try adding `setuptools` in your `install_requires` list, and try again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: *`setuptools`* is missing.

---

It looks like you have *click v7.1.2*. In that version one of the code paths to figure out the version number automatically uses *`pkg_resources`* which is a top-level package of *setuptools*:

```py
                try:
                    import pkg_resources
                except ImportError:
                    pass
                else:
                    for dist in pkg_resources.working_set:
                        scripts = dist.get_entry_map().get("console_scripts") or {}
                        for _, entry_point in iteritems(scripts):
                            if entry_point.module_name == module:
                                ver = dist.version
                                break
```

-- https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/7.1.2/src/click/decorators.py#L283-L293

So in a way, *click* depends on *setuptools*. But there are other code paths that do not require `pkg_resources`, for example the version number can be set explicitly in the parameters of the decorator (if I am not mistaken): `@click.version_option(version='1.2.3')` ([doc](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/?highlight=version#click.version_option)), in such a case *setuptools* is not a mandatory dependency.

In most cases, it just works because (out of what I would call a coincidence) *setuptools* is almost always pre-installed (in virtual environments for example). But "*almost always*" is not the same as "*always*", and for example it is absolutely possible to have environments (virtual or not) that do not have a *setuptools* installation. And this looks like it is exactly what happens in the case of a *pex*-packaged application. I believe *pex* creates clean virtual environments (i.e. without *pip*, *setuptools* or *wheel* or anything else).

Since *setuptools* is not declared as a dependency it is not installed, importing *`pkg_resources`* fails, and finding the version string fails.

I would say that this is a failure on *click*'s side. They should either declare *setuptools* as a mandatory dependency, or at least as an optional dependency (in an *extra*) and document this properly.

A possible fix is to add *setuptools* as a direct dependency of your application: add `setuptools` to the list of `install_requires` in your `setup.py`.

Note that as far as I can tell, things will change in *click v8*. Finding out the version string will rely on *`importlib.metadata`* from the standard library (back-ported to *Python < 3.8* as *`importlib_metadata`*) instead of *`pkg_resources`*:

- https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/1488
- https://github.com/pallets/click/pull/1582

From the looks of it, it will cause problems again, probably even more. Since *click* still does not declare [*`importlib-metadata`*](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) as a dependency for older Python versions where [*`importlib.metadata`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) is not in the standard library (*< 3.8*), the version string lookup will fail.